# find matching value in a column based on other vector

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, list-manipulation

I have a data frame and vector like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(orig = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                  proxy = c(1,43,65,2,44,45,46,3,55),
                  dist = c(0, 100,101, 10, 1000, 5000, 5001,0,3))

v <- c(1,45:100)
```

I now want the following:

For each unique value in `df1$orig` (here it's a numeric for simplicity, but it could be character too), if the same `orig` value is not available in `v`, find the best proxy that has the lowest `dist`.

In this example the first value in `df1$orig` is 1 and this value is available in `v` as well, so we take it.
The second unique value in `df$orig` is 2 and this is not available in `v`. The best proxy with the lowest `dist` is 44 in this case, but it is not in `v` either. The next best is 45 and this value is in `v` so we take it.
The third unique value in `df1$orig` is 3 and there is no 3 in `v`. The best proxy here is 55.

the solution is c(1,45,55)

Note that the first value for each `orig` in `proxy` is the `orig` value.
`dist` is sorted here but not necessarily the case always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a couple of steps with {dplyr}: keep the proxies that are in `v`, sort by `dist` and pick the first for each `orig`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(proxy %in% v) %>% 
  arrange(dist) %>% 
  group_by(orig) %>% 
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   orig [3]
#>    orig proxy  dist
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     0
#> 2     2    45  5000
#> 3     3    55     3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In case you are beside a *dplyr* solution also interested in a *base* solution.

Fist reduce to those which have a match between `proxy` and `v`, then `order` by `orig` and `dist` and then take those which are not `duplicated`.

```
tt <- df1[df1$proxy %in% v,]
tt <- tt[order(tt$orig, tt$dist),]
tt[!duplicated(tt$orig),]
#  orig proxy dist
#1    1     1    0
#6    2    45 5000
#9    3    55    3
```

Or in case you losse some `orig` when there is not match between `proxy` and `v` you can use:

```
tt <- df1[df1$proxy %in% v,]
tt <- tt[order(tt$orig, tt$dist),]
tt <- tt[!duplicated(tt$orig),c("orig", "proxy")]
tt$proxy[match(unique(df1$orig), tt$orig)]
#[1]  1 45 55
```